# Given a morphism of ring $f : A \rightarrow B$ how can we view $B \otimes M$ for M being an A module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ morphism of rings.

There is something I am confused about if M is an A-module. I am little bit confused about when we consider $B \otimes M$ as either A module or B module. When we consider $B \otimes M$ as A module. Do we consider the tensor as tensor in A ? That is, do we write $B \otimes_A M$ ? If we consider $B \otimes M$ as B module do we consider the tensor $B \otimes_B M$ ? Or is it just $B \otimes_A M$ where we can either put an A module structure on this or a B module strcuture on this ?

Comment: You've put something in the title which seems relevant, and the body of your question is a mess.  Also, your title does not tell us what the question is.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't know how I can write this question in a good way, because it is kinda of confusing. What would you suggest?

Comment: well for one, what is "tensor tensor" supposed to mean?  More seriously: it would help if you could explain the context in which your confusion arose.  Is this Atiyah McDonald?  Was there a specific expression where it was unclear whether they meant $\otimes_A$ or $\otimes_B$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yea this is from Atiyah McDonald.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that the morphism $f:A \to B$ allows us to view the ring $B$ as an $A$ module with the multiplication
$$
ab := f(a)b
$$
Moreover, any $B$-module $N$ may be regarded as an $A$-module with the similarly defined $an := f(a)n$. This is sometimes called a [restriction of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Restriction_of_scalars).

My attempt to answer your question: $M \otimes_A N$ is necessarily a tensor product of $A$-modules, and $M \otimes_B N$ is necessarily a tensor product of $B$-modules.  Given the above morphism, any $B$-module may be regarded as an $A$ module, but an $A$-module cannot necessarily be considered as a $B$-module.

If $N$ is an $A$-module (but not a $B$-module), then $B \otimes_B N$ makes no sense, since we have no "scalar" multiplication defined between elements of $b$ and elements of $N$.  However, $B \otimes_A N$ is fine, since $B$ is an $A$-module.

If $N$ is a $B$-module, then $B \otimes N$ is ambiguous; it could be either $B \otimes_B N$ or $B \otimes_A N$.  In that case, some more context is required.

Then again, $B \otimes_B N \cong N$, so it is unlikely that $B \otimes N$ would refer to the former case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes my confusion go away. This answers all my questions.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: Just wanted to know something small though. If we have $B \otimes_A M$ with M being a A-module, then we can view this as B module by $b (a \otimes_A m) \mapsto a \otimes_A bm$ right ?

Comment: I think you mean that we can define
$$
b' \otimes_A (bm) := bb' \otimes_A m 
$$
With $b,b' \in B$ and $m \in M$. I think the way you've expressed it is an abuse of notation, but it could be sensibly done.  Really, what you're doing is applying an extension of scalars on $M$.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay thanks a lot. I will read that part on extension of scalars. I think it will clear a lot of things for me. Thanks.